# Cannot find module 'Text.HTML.TagSoup'

Tags: haskell

I have installed tagsoup with

cabal v1-install tagsoup

and verified the install with ghc-pkg list | grep tagsoup

However, in my very simple Haskell 8.6.5 program the statement

import Text.HTML.TagSoup

fails with cannot find module 'Text.HTML.TagSoup'

ghc -v is not useful
cabal new-install tagsoup fails with a ton of errors

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as CL

main :: IO ()
main = do
    lbs <- simpleHttp "https://wiki.haskell.org"
    print $ show lbs
    -- tagsoup code removed
```

Comment: Have you created Cabal project?

Comment: The comment from arrowd is key. If your program has a cabal file, then you need to put a dependency on tagsoup in the cabal file. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of a single file use case, I'd recommend using a Stack script. If you add the following two lines to the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.27 script
```

You can then run `stack filename.hs`, which will:

1. Download GHC if necessary
2. Download and build all dependencies, based on your import list
3. Use `runghc` to run your program

More information:

- [How to Script](https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/stack-script)
- [Get Started with Haskell](https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/get-started)